# Would + a stative verb

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

As far as I know, here's the main difference between `used to` and `would`: `used to` can be used with both dynamic and stative verbs, whereas `would` can only be used with dynamic (action) verbs. It's a sentence I saw in a textbook:

> He *would* always know the answers.

Is it OK to use `know`, which is a stative verb, with `would`?

Comment: Yes, that's fine (cf. "he always knew the answers"). Incidentally, "know" does not entirely exclude the progressive, as in "He claims that fewer and fewer students are knowing how to write English when they come up to university". And the verb is "use", not "used to"; a small point but worth remembering.

Comment: @BillJ [devil's advocating here] It's doubtful if the verb is actually *use*, though. There's quite a lot of evidence that it's *used*. Although there's no quibble about the *to* not being part of the verb, of course.

Comment: @Araucaria What evidence? I've never seen any

Comment: @BillJ Well, first of all consider what the verb *use* sounds like. I mean does it rhyme with the noun *the use of* or does it rhyme with the regular verb in *I used the computer*. If it's the second, then how come the verb in *used always to ...* has a /t/ and not a /d/? Secondly, look at the [very large numbers of the form *didn't used to* available in published books](https://www.google.co.uk/?client=firefox-b#q=%22didn%27t+used+to%22&tbm=bks&start=30)  and which also occur regularly in adults' writing ...

Comment: @BillJ ... strongly suggesting that the plain form is, at least for many speakers, *used* not *use*. More evidence for this is that in runs like *didn't he used always to ....* there is often an audible /t/ between *used* and the following vowel. There's more but I can't remember it right now :)

Comment: @Araucaria But there is no verb "used". The problem is that "used to” is pronounced with a single /t/ and hence is homophonous with the “use to” in “He didn’t use to smoke”. Since the verb is undoubtedly "use", then that is the plain form which is obligatory after auxiliary "do", as in "I didn't use to smoke" (not *"I didn't used to smoke"). Yes, you do see "didn't used to" quite a lot, but it's not right. Btw, I very much dislike "didn't he used always to ...". It's quite unnatural to me. Much better to say "didn't he always use to ..."

Comment: @BillJ But it's only "not right" because presecriptivist spelling is trying to regularise the plain form. Why do you say the verb is undoubtedly *use*? And is that /ju:s/ or /ju:z/? [you can find five or six uses of 'didn't used to' on LanguageLog, btw]

Comment: @Araucaria. Have you tried to find the verb "used" in any dictionary? It's not being prescriptivist; it's just a simple fact that the verb is "use". Even the Oxford dictionary says that, and indeed supports everything I've said.

Comment: Here's a link to the Oxford On-line entry for "use". If you scroll down, you'll come to 'Usage': [link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use)

Comment: @BillJ Bill!? [You're asking me to take grammar advice from a dictionary?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-word-parts). I didn't think we did things like that, you and me?

Comment: @BillJ I think you'll find this LanguageLog post by Mark Liberman very interesting indeed: [**"didn't use(d) to be"**](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2756). Notice that Liberman finds *didn't use to be* ungrammatical and *didn't used to be* grammatical ... . It's an interesting one!

Comment: @Araucaria I know, lol! - they are notorious aren't they. It's just that with "use" they i.e. Cambridge, MacMillan etc.all say the same thing (did you check out the Oxford, btw?). And there are other non-dictionary resources too such as the BBC Learning English [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1346_gramchallenge15/). I saw Liberman's post a while back, but passed quietly over it with the intention of asking GKP for his thoughts (I'll do that now).

Comment: @BillJ I might have a story to tell you about GKP in the near future ... Will let you know. I must stay off this website till I've finished my work!!! Have a nice bank holiday weekend.

Comment: @Araucaria All the best, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially correct in that stative verbs usually relate to a permanent or extended state, and you cannot use **would** to describe a permanent or extended state. For example, you cannot replace **used to** with **would** in these sentences:

> My grandma used to live in Indonesia.
>   We used to live in York.

We use **would** about regular, habitual actions- a number of separate occasions over a period of time: that's why you can't use it for permanent of extended states.

You are also correct in saying that **know** can be a stative verb. If you know something, then (assuming you don't forget) it's not a temporary thing.

You can, however, use **know** in a non-stative way, for example if you were to say

> Every time somebody asked a question, John would always know the answer.

What this means is that, on every separate occasion that a question was asked, John did, on every separate occasion, know the answer.

[This link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page6.shtml) provides more background information about **would** and **used to**.